# If T(n) = n √ n, what will be its closest O-notation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If T(n) = n √ n, then T(n) is O(?).

I am a little bit confused regarding its answer. Please help me in this.

I was practising for an exam and this question had 4 options. What should be the correct answer?
1. T(n) is O(n3)
 2. T(n) is O(n log n)
 3. T(n) is O(n)
 4. None of these

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with O(n√n)?

Comment: I was practising for an exam and this question had 4 options. What should be the correct answer?
1. T(n) is O(n3)
 2. T(n) is O(n log n)
 3. T(n) is O(n)
 4. None of these

Comment: It's `O(n sqrt(n))`, read up on the definition of the big O notation, it;s fun and not that hard if you give yourself some time to understand all the notations. So 'none of these' seems correct. Since it's a practice exam, can't you just lookup the answer?

Comment: I have updated my question and want to know from the available choices. Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, but would you have as much problem if they had written `T(n) = n^(3/2)` instead?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know the definition of big-O? Did you try to substitute the answers into the definition and see which are true?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried or what it is that you don't understand. StackOverflow is not for answering your exam or homework problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O-notation is defined as anything *less than or equal to* its argument. e.g. `n` and `n sqrt n` are both `O(n^2)`, but only the former is `O(n log n)`.

Thus the answer is **(1)**, because only `O(n^3)` has a greater complexity than `n sqrt n`.

---

EDIT: for a proof of why `log n` is less than `sqrt n` (or any other positive power of `n`), see [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial).

Answer (score 0):

T(n)=O( n √ n), it's really simple! The big-O notation is try to use the input size (that is n) to denote the time complexity, and the above answer meet the need!